# Anyone else with bad font smoothing in Brackets 1.1?

Tags: web, editor, adobe, adobe-brackets, font-smoothing

So I've got [Mactype](https://code.google.com/p/mactype/) installed which renders fonts beautifully on my Windows setup, but since I  installed the latest version of Brackets v1.1 the font smoothing/anti-aliasing has been terrible.

Here's a comparison between version 1.0 and 1.1 .

### **v1.0**

[image: v1.0]

### **v1.1**

[image: v1.1]

I'm really not sure why it looks like this, I have tried clearing everything related with Brackets in `~\Appdata\Roaming\Brackets\` thinking it might be a conflict with some extensions I had installed but that didn't work, I'm guessing its a bug in the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm answering my own question, after doing a ton of research on the issue, I found out this was similar with font rendering issues I had been having in Chrome with mactype, I posted the [issue](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/10698) on brackets' github and luckily someone else had the [same bug](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/10398#issuecomment-83554972) in v1.2 and was able to get it working by starting a shortcut to Brackets with the switch `--disable-direct-write` .

Just append the switch to the end of your shortcut's target like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\Brackets.exe" --disable-direct-write
```

And make sure you're starting brackets from the shortcut. :)